# How do you change the screen so that when you click anywhere on the screen, you go from the problem to the answer?

Tags: java, android

I have a math problem, 1+1. How can I change the app screen so that when the screen is clicked, the screen changes from 1+1 to just one number, 2?

I have created a couple of text views and a horizontal divider. I am new to java, and only know javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an `OnClickListener` to your `TextView` and change the text.

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textview.setText("2");
        }
    });
```

Now the `TextView` changes the text on a click on the `TextView`.
It's difficult to understand, but I think you want to change the text on a random click position. So set an `OnClickListener` to the main Layout.

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/layout"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 //Your TextViews...

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textview.setText("2");
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to declare the variables.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
Textview textview= (Textview)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```